# Comma separated values to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written below code. It is not working

**INPUT**

```
A,B,C,D
```

**QUERY(That I have tried so far)**

```
Declare @products nvarchar(max)='A,B,C,D'
Declare @individual nvarchar(max)

Declare @Jurisdiction table
(
     JurisdictionX nvarchar(max)
)
WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%,%',@products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products, 0, PATINDEX('%,%',@products))
        SELECT @individual

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products, LEN(@individual + ',') + 1,
                                                     LEN(@products))
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
       SET @individual = @products
       SET @products = NULL
       Insert into @Jurisdiction values(@individual);
    END
END

Select * from @Jurisdiction;
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
COLS
.....
 A
 B
 C
 D
```

I want to perform insert operation. It's not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: iS the insert not working? or loop not working?

Comment: You haven't declared **@individual** @Nida

Comment: you have not declared the +@products and +@individual variables in the query provided. Also what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to insert `Comma Separated Values` to rows.

For that you can use this query

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(MAX)='A,B,C,D'

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),',','.'),1) 'Ids' 
FROM  
(
     -- Select the string in XML format
     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data         
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc123/1)**

**UPDATE : According to the code given by OP**

```
Declare @products nvarchar(max)='A,B,C,D'
Declare @individual nvarchar(max)

Declare @Jurisdiction table
(
JurisdictionX nvarchar(max)
)
WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
IF PATINDEX('%,%',@products) > 0
BEGIN
SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products, 0, PATINDEX('%,%',@products))
SELECT @individual

SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products, LEN(@individual + ',') + 1,
                                     LEN(@products))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @individual = @products
SET @products = NULL
Insert into @Jurisdiction values(@individual);
END
END

Select * from @Jurisdiction;
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert **Comma Separated Values** to rows? @Nida

Comment: The query I have posted is working here. What are the values inside **@products** variable? Can you give me sample data in **@products**? @Nida

Comment: ontana,Nebraska,Pennsylvania,Montana,Nebraska,Pennsylvania,New Mexico,New York,

Comment: Its getting inserted here according to the values u gave. What error are you getting? @Nida

Comment: Table @Jurisdiction is empty

Comment: Can u try my code that I gave first. It perfectly converts CSV to rows. Please leave a reply after done. @Nida

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't specify the column name: `JurisdictionX`

Try this: `Insert into @Jurisdiction(JurisdictionX) values(@individual);`